# Trigonometric Substitution Evaluate ∫(x^3)/(sqrt(9-4x^2))dx

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate ∫(x^3)/(sqrt(9-4x^2))dx. i started by making the bottom sqrt((3)^2-(2x)^2)) and let 2x=3sinu so, 2dx= 3cosudu => dx=(3/2)*cosudu and then i plugged the new values in and got ∫(((3/2)sinu)^3 ((3/2)cosu))/3cosu)du . now i have no idea what else to do with this problem!

Comment: Before anything else you need to make sure your algebra is correct.  How did you turn $9-4x^2$ into $(9x)^2-4^2$?

Comment: sorry, i wrote half of the problem wrong. i editted it, do you have any ideas now? @David

Comment: I assume you mean "$2x=3\sin u$"?

Comment: yes @CameronBuie

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950109/integrate-by-trig-substitution, with bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify everything you can, then you will need to find
$$\int \sin^3u\,du=\int (1-\cos^2u)\sin u\,du$$
by substituting $y=\cos u$.

However this is not really a case for a trigonometric substitution.  Unless you were told you have to do it that way, it's easier to go back to the start and substitute $v=9-4x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

For calculation of  $\displaystyle \int \sin^3 udu::$

Using the formula $\bullet\ \displaystyle \sin(3u)=3\sin (u)-4\sin^3 (u)\Rightarrow \sin^3(u) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\left(3\sin (u)-4\sin(3u)\right)$

Now Integrate both side w. r .to $u$

$\displaystyle \int \sin^3(u)du = \displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\int \left(3\sin (u)-4\sin(3u)\right)du = -\frac{3}{4}\cdot \cos(u)+\frac{1}{3}\cos(3u)+\mathcal{C}$